# How to sort the order of the nested array object using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Having a nested array object, trying to sort it based on the order value present in my object.

So, am splitting the object and pushing it into two new array variables.
But in one of my object response there is an array, i need to sort the values in ascending order. Here it is what I have tried.

JS:

```
var obj = {details:[{type:"general",order:1,},{type:"general1",order:3,},{type:"static",order:4,list:[{type:"static2",order:3,},{type:"static1",order:2,},]},{type:"general2",order:2,}]};

var basicArray = [];
var listArray = [];
var sortedArray = "";
var sortedListArray = "";
var checkListArray = [];

var objDetails = obj.details;
sortedArray = _.sortBy(objDetails,"order");

for(var i=0;i<sortedArray.length;i++){
    if(sortedArray[i].list){
        listArray.push(sortedArray[i]);
    }
    else{
        basicArray.push(sortedArray[i]);
    }
}

for(var j=0;j<listArray.length;j++){
    if(listArray[j].list){
        for(var k=0;k<listArray[j].list.length;k++){
            sortedListArray = _.sortBy(listArray[k].list,"order");
            checkListArray.push(listArray[k].list);
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo URL](http://jsfiddle.net/bmk7n7o5/)

So the expected output is in my second loop, i want to order the values of my array, like I did in my first loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sortBy on list :

```
for(var i=0;i<sortedArray.length;i++){
    if(sortedArray[i].list){
        sortedArray[i].list =_.sortBy(sortedArray[i].list,"order");
        checkListArray.push(sortedArray[i].list);    // add sorted list to checklist
        basicArray.push(sortedArray[i]);     // add element with sorted list to basic array
    }
    else{
        basicArray.push(sortedArray[i]);
    }
}
```